# Google Apps Script running slow due to for loop

Tags: rss, spreadsheet

I have a google apps scripts that takes a spreadsheet, and loops over the rows, getting the value column by column and generating an RSS feed.

I have some performance issues, and it's due to the foor loop I think, and querying that many values.

Any insights on how to optimize this? Thanks!

http://pastebin.com/EPN5EPAx

Comment: The linked page was removed

Answer (score 2):

Calling `getCell` and `setValue` over and over again is probably what is slowing it down so much. Each time you call `setValue()` it makes a new IO call which is slow. It''s best to load and save your data all in one fell swoop.

For example, load all the values from the range at the start with:

```
var values = range.getValues();
```

Then iterate through he resulting two dimensional array (instead of `getCell(i, 2)` use `values[i - 1][1]`).

When you need to change a value use:

```
values[i][j] = newValue;
```

Then when you're finished call:

```
range.setValues(values);
```

This way you minimize the IO calls to two: one to load at the start and one save changes at the end.